# Display dynamic width of container in WPF

Tags: wpf

```
 <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.55*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Gray">
            <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeeNameTextBlock"                      
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="50,0,0,0"                                      
                             FontSize="18"
                               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                               Text="Content09asdfadsdsdasdfasd92168132 "                       
                               TextWrapping="NoWrap"                       
                            />
            <ToggleButton x:Name="btn"                                                                  
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"                                
                                  Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  Height="30" 
                                  Width="30"  >
                Button
            </ToggleButton>
        </StackPanel>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Background="Yellow" />
    </Grid>
```

This is my code i have issue in displaying the toggle button, you can refer to screen shot below for currently displaying and expectation

conditions
* button should be always end of the text block even content is small or big
* if content is bigger then container, textbox size should stop at before less width of button. so that we can see toggle button on display. as shown in expected screen shot.

Result Screenshot long text
[image: Result Screenshot]

Result Screenshot small text
[image]

Expected screenshot long text
[image: Expected screenshot]

[image]

Expected Screenshot small text

Please any one help on this

Thanks in advance

**Solution**

```
 <Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.55*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Name="rightBlk" Background="Green" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Gray">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeeNameTextBlock"                      
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="50,0,0,0"
                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                       FontSize="18"
                       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                       Text="Content09asasdfasdfd "                       
                       TextWrapping="NoWrap"  
                       Padding="0,0,30,0" 
                    />
            <ToggleButton x:Name="btn"       
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"                                
                          Margin="0,0,0,0" 

                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          Height="30" 
                          Width="30"  >
                Button
            </ToggleButton>

        </Grid>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Background="Yellow" />
    </Grid>
```

Code Behide

```
private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {            
            EmployeeNameTextBlock.MaxWidth = ((Grid)sender).ActualWidth - 50 - rightBlk.ActualWidth;
        }
```

Thank you @lvan and @Neptune for helping me to solve this issue.

Comment: I tried your code as is in Blend and got the expected result actually!

Comment: thanks for your response Neptune but actully code renders the window in result screen shot not expected. because then text in textbox is very large that will push the button more then the first column size, which will not be visible like in first screen shot.

Comment: you can add more text in textbox to replicate this issue for you @Neptune

Comment: Yes got you now. I will add an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the StackPanel with a Grid. This way you have more control on distribution and can give your Button priority to get its width first before allocating the remaining to the TextBlock:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.55*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Gray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeeNameTextBlock"                      
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="50,0,0,0"
                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                       FontSize="18"
                       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                       Text="Content09asdfadsdsdasdfasd92168132 "                       
                       TextWrapping="NoWrap"                       
                    />
    <ToggleButton x:Name="btn"       Grid.Column="1"                                                           
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"                                
                          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          Height="30" 
                          Width="30"  >
        Button
    </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Background="Yellow" />
</Grid>
```

I added an attribute `TextTrimming` if you want to indicate to user there's missing text but you can remove it if that's not needed.

The code above produces this result when the width is limited:
[image]

Comment: Once again thank @Neptune but you have missed my first condition the button should be always end of text.

Comment: The button does display at end of text. Haven't you got the same result as in the screenshot I added?

Comment: I agree when text is large please try the text with small, it will not support the required view. button will be separated with text.

Comment: Would aligning the TextBlock text to Left produce the intended outcome? Or do you need the text to be centered along with the button?

Comment: no Neptune, text should be left only. it will not work with just left align because the textbox was left align by stackpanel using orientation. but the button is aligned right in your answer. you can see my expectation result screenshot 2 how it should look if small text.

Comment: hope my updated screenshot will give you more details of what i want it and what is been displayed even with your code @Neptune thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you are looking for with either you code and adding 
`MaxWidth="270"` and `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` to textbox

or Neptunes code and changing 
`<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />` to "Auto" and also adding `MaxWidth="270"` to textbox.

I don't think you can do it without setting a MaxWidth on the textbox but that means you'll have to recalculate it if you resize your window.

To recalculate: 
Subscribe to main window size changed event:

`SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;` within main window constructor or in xaml

And add to codebehind:

```
private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    EmployeeNameTextBlock.MaxWidth = StackPanelName.ActualWidth - btn.ActualWidth;
}
```

You might need to use .Width instead of Actual width, and you can also try using the column instead of the stack panel but this illustrates the recalculation you need to do.

Comment: Thank you @Ivan, if we fix maxwidth for 270px then the width will not increase with window it stays to 270px when resized as you said right.

you are thought are similar to mine, i was looking similar to you last point. i want something, which dynamically take maxsize for textbox based on (column width - button width) so that button always displays.

Comment: Edited to show how to dynamically recalculate. I don't think you can do it without it, would love to know if it is possible though. :)

Comment: Yes Ivan after you previous comment changes help from Neptune, i tried the similar type and i have achieved the expected result. you can find solution under by question. Thank you @lvan  your suggestion helped me a solve this issue. You can find solution under by updated question.